# Creating an SSL certificate for a subdomain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, fileserver

I've been looking up how to create a SSL certificate for my fileserver subdomain on GoDaddy. Unfortunately, this is not a service they offer as a company. From what I've read, it seems the best option is to create a virtual server and generate one that way which I have never done before and don't exactly have the time to create.

Any other options or suggestions?

Comment: You can use Let's Encrypt, but sometimes there are many issues and you need to renew it periodically. It will better for you to use basic SSL.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a VPS, you can install Let's Encrypt. How to install and setup let's encrypt on domain or subdomain, you can give a look to tutorial

[How to get FREE SSL certificate for any website?](https://www.insqo.com/get-free-ssl-certificate-website/)